# How do you include Xml Docs for a class library in a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I am creating a NuGet package for a C# class library, and I would like to include generated Xml Documentation with the library. This is my nuspec file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>MyLibrary</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <authors>John Nelson</authors>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <description>A C# class library</description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\..\build\MyLibrary.dll" target="lib\Net40" />
    <file src="..\..\build\MyLibrary.xml" target="lib\Net40" />
  </files>
</package>
```

When I [build the package with this command](http://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package):

```
nuget pack MyLibrary.nuspec
```

It generates an error. If I remove the line:

```
<file src="..\..\build\MyLibrary.xml" target="lib\Net40" />
```

NuGet.exe successfully creates the nupkg. I can even unzip the package, and verify that the contents are correct. What am I doing wrong? Should the xml file go into a different target directory?

Comment: What command do you use to build the package?

Comment: @ColonelPanic updated question with command and link to docs.

Comment: Thanks John. I am packaging a csproj directly `nuget pack library.csproj` (I don't have a nuspec), but the fix works the same.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't check "Generate Xml Documentation" for the build configuration I was using. That nuspec is correct.

[image]

Comment: Good to know.  I was trying my hand at using the GUI to create a package, and it was trying to get me to move the XML file to the content folder instead of lib.  Didn't seem right, so I wanted to get a second opinion.  Glad you had this post.  :-)

Comment: How do I load the generated file from code so that I can read it? I suppose I would need to know the value in this setting, and I would also need to know the path of the project. I've tried using `asm.Location` and this gets me inside of `bin\Debug\netcoreapp` etc.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the screenshot. This box has to be also check in **Release** mode. Easy to miss :-(.

Answer (score 36):

In .NET Core/Standard you can do this by editing the project XML file, for example:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\$(AssemblyName).xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will output the documentation as an XML file next to your output assembly.

**EDIT:**
As a side note once you enable `GenerateDocumentationFile` you will probably get lots of warnings on your public methods for not having added full documentation tags.  If you want to disable these warnings simply add in the `PropertyGroup`:

```
<NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
```

Comment: `<GenerateDocumentationFile>` results in a `<DocumentationFile>` already, so I think only one of both is required, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc

Comment: Specifiying `<DocumentationFile>` yourself just allows you to output the file where ever you want.  If you dont specify it I think it literally puts it in the path I have provided above.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to simply add the first half of @bytedev's answer. This defaults to the correct location and will be packaged correctly.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```