# NuGet Package not copying XMLDoc file along with dll to bin

Tags: package, nuget, xml-documentation

I'm using NuGet GUI and trying to include XML File along with my DLL to distribute help along with the DLL.

When I install package in any of the project, it adds the DLL reference successfully, but XML file is not generated inside bin folder of the project in which package is added.

XML file is available within packages\\lib\.XML

[image: NuGet Package Builder GUI]

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have copy local set to true for the ingenious*.dll after it gets added as a reference?

Answer (score 2):

On your side of things:

Check this post:

[How do you include Xml Docs for a class library in a NuGet package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205738/how-do-you-include-xml-docs-for-a-class-library-in-a-nuget-package)

On the developer's side of things:

The creator of the NuGet package decides some of this.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package

Find : **Automatically Running PowerShell Scripts During Package Installation and Removal**

So I think the developer of the Nuget package would have to write the voo-doo.

Or you'll have to manually include it yourself.

Comment: I have already came across & read those articles before i posted this question. They are not using NuGet GUI. With GUI i don't need nuspec at all. From the attached screen shot do you think there's anything else to be done to achieve what i desire?

Comment: Looks to me like your answer is about how to include xml docs with a nuget package. 
The OP has a nuget package that already has xml docs and is asking why they aren't copied over to the bin folder. How does your answer address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Both the .dll and the .xml file should be copied to your project's output folder when the project is compiled.

NuGet will not copy the .xml file, nor the .dll, in your bin folder when you install the package. If you want to do this then you will have to use PowerShell. I do not believe you need to do this since MSBuild will do this anyway at compile time.

Comment: i will try PowerSheell and would let you know. MSBuild is not copying it automatically.for me.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am in the same situation.