# Copy xml from nuget dependency to output

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a nuget package in which I have an xml file, say, `config.xml`. I want this file to be copied to the `bin` folder of any dependent project. However, regardless of how I try to specify this file or where I put it based on various guides I've found, I can't manage to get it copied.

If I rename my `.nupkg` to `*.nupkg.zip` and look at it in explorer, it has the following internal structure:

```
package root
|-- lib
|    +-- net45
|          |-- My.Own.Library.dll
|          +-- My.Own.Library.xml
+-- config.xml
```

When I build the dependent project, I get something like this in my bin folder:

```
bin
|-- My.Own.Program.exe
|-- My.Own.Library.dll
+-- My.Own.Library.xml
```

Note that `config.xml` isn't included here. How do I, preferrably from the nuget specification of the package (rather than in the dependent project) make sure that `config.xml` is copied into the `bin` folder when the program is built?

---

Some additional info:

I have in the `project.json` file of the library which generates the nuget packge, the following specification:

```
"packInclude": {
  "/": "config.xml",
  "lib/net45/": "config.xml"
},
"contentFiles": [
  "config.xml"
],
```

However, this doesn't seem to generate anything in the `.nuspec` file that is included in the package in the output folder. I found [these instructions](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#contentfiles-with-visual-studio-2015-update-1-and-later), and edited the generated `.nuspec` manually to match:

```
<contentFiles>
  <files include="contentFiles/any/any/certificates.xml" copyToOutput="true" />
</contentFiles>
```

This didn't have any effect at all in the dependent project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NuGet Package not copying XMLDoc file along with dll to bin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136999/nuget-package-not-copying-xmldoc-file-along-with-dll-to-bin)

Answer (score -1):

NuPack is an open source project under MIT licence that natively do what you need :

- https://github.com/Virtuoze/NuPack
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuPack

It is a nugget package that automatically create a package on build time.
You can try it and see how it manage the feature you need.

It seems that it include a build folder in nuget package with a .targets file to include a post build process to copy with dependencies files.