# How can i install a nuget package with xmldocument

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

My project depends on some modules(nuget packages), and I have pack xml document in the packages.

When I install-package them in , xmldocument files of modules are not in my folder. I renamed a **.nupkg** file to **.zip**, unzip it ,.xml (xmldocument) is in the zip package.

How can I install the .xml documentation in my main project folder?

**Update：**

My project is based on Abp (abp.io), I have finished main modules,and build a aspnet core project to reference the modules.because the project contains a WebApi, I want get some module 's xmlDocument ,then the swagger info cause the project contains a WebApi, I want get some module 's xmlDocument ,then the swagger info will be perfect.

Now , My way is use post build event update the .xml files to a folder.It can solve my problem, but I want to see an idea , can use it by reference packages directly.

Comment: Sorry, but what does _modules (dlls) xml document_ mean?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski  it means moduleA.dll ,moduleA.xml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52891727

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9498

Comment: Is your class library a net standard project or net framework project?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski,Yes,it is a .netstandard2.0 project.

Comment: @menxin, what did you mean? Did you want to use a post-build event to copy all the indeed xml documents into a folder and then pack them into the nuget package?

Comment: And when you use my function, it is actually as content in the solution explorer of the project.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `XmlDocument` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netcore-3.1)? Because thats a class structure to deal with XML-files and makes little sense to me in context of the question.

Comment: @menxin ,When you install that package, the related xml document exists under the outputpath of the main project. Then you can use `XmlDocument` to load the file from the outputpath of your main project.And for net core projects, we cannot use the `xxx.xml` file directly and shoud import them in the main project. I think you could have a try on my answer.   Also,more detailed points should be explained if I misunderstand your issue. Look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: @Lennart , it is xml documentation comments,  sorry , hhaha ,my english.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i install a nuget package with xmldocument

Actually, the xml docuement could be in the lib folder in the `nuget.nupkg` folder. However, it is only be imported into output folder of a net framework project with [packages.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config) nuget manage format.

If you install your nuget package with [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) in a net framework project or install it into new sdk project(`Net Core` or `Net Standard`), the xml document file will not output to the project's bin folder.

**So I assume your main project is a net core project.**

**Also**, there is [an open github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3587) which reflects this strange behavior `xxx.pdb` and `xxx.xml` file.

So I suggest you could use [Content and ContentFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files) node which is suitable for setting this xml document file into all types of projects.

Please add these node in your xxx.csproj file of the net standard class library project:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="xxxx\<project_name>.xml" (the path of the xml document file) Pack="true" PackagePath="content\any\any;contentFiles\any\any\;;">
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>         
      </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Then** you can pack this nuget project(right-click on the projecy-->**Pack**) and when you install this package in a new project, it will output the document file in the output folder of the main project during build process.

Comment: I tried it your way. i can also use your way, as it will appear